# helm does not find the chart in my chart repo

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I created a helm chart repo via Github Action [helm/chart-releaser-action](https://github.com/helm/chart-releaser-action)

URL: https://syself.github.io/hetzner-cloud-controller-manager/index.yaml

content:

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  hetzner-cloud-controller-manager:
  - apiVersion: v2
    created: "2023-05-03T14:58:46.608886766Z"
    digest: 4f1d8ded0ad0b025a36fb98a47c92c633681ab61028e7e28e8219d4fd0452071
    name: hetzner-cloud-controller-manager
    type: application
    urls:
    - https://github.com/syself/hetzner-cloud-controller-manager/releases/download/hetzner-cloud-controller-manager-0.14.0-beta1/hetzner-cloud-controller-manager-0.14.0-beta1.tgz
    version: 0.14.0-beta1
generated: "2023-05-04T09:32:19.598263437Z"
```

I added the repo and updated it:

```
helm repo add syself-hetzner-ccm https://syself.github.io/hetzner-cloud-controller-manager

helm repo update syself-hetzner-ccm
```

But if I search for the chart in the repo, I don't get a result:

```
helm search repo syself
No results found
```

I tried to use `--debug`, but I just can't find the chart via `helm`.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helm` does not show beta releases by default. If you use it like this (with **--devel**), it works:

```
❯ helm search repo syself --devel
NAME                                                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                               
syself-hetzner-ccm/hetzner-cloud-controller-man...      0.14.0-beta2                    Hetzner cloud-controller-manager by Syself
```